# Can I use present simple instead of present continuous for a temporary but regular thing

Tags: tense, present-continuous

Every july she goes to Italy and stays 3 weeks at the "Pizza" hotel

Is it possible in this case to use present simple instead of present continuous because  it is regular (every) but temporary (3 weeks) stay

Comment: It is the natural tense to use in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: that is the normal tense.

> She is going to Italy.

would mean that she is going right at this moment (or is intending to go to in the near future, but that is a different use).

I can't think of a context or meaning where a native speaker would say

> *Every July she is going to Italy.

Saying that would mark somebody out as a foreigner.

Comment: my question was on the verb "stay" but thanks for your answer

Comment: she stays 3 weeks each time, it is also a regular habit.

Comment: The same applies, @user5577. _She is staying_ is now, or her intention in the near future. _She stays_: Her habit or regular practice